# Undo Action from SnackBar Component

Tags: angular, angular-material2, snackbar

I need to create some undo logic from the snackBar custom component. I am facing challnge in calling the undo logic function from the custom snackBar Component.

**SnackBar Service :**

```
showSnackbar(mes: string){
    let snackRef=this.snackBar.openFromComponent(SnakebarComponent, {
              duration : 2000,
               data: mes
                   });
  }
```

**SnackBar Component:**

```
constructor(@Inject(MAT_SNACK_BAR_DATA) public data: any) { }
  message = this.data;

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onClick(){
     // Undo Button of custom component
  }
```

**Component calling snackBar**

```
this._utility.showSnackbar('Saved Successfull!!');
```

Please help me out in achieving the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose you're probably looking for this method `dismissWithAction()`. In your function, call `dismissWithAction()` on the Snackbar's reference which closes the snackbar.

From the official documentation:

> `dismissWithAction`: Marks the snackbar action clicked - [Angular Material - `MatSnackBarRef` API](https://material.angular.io/components/snack-bar/api#MatSnackBarRef)

Example:

```ts
// ...
export class CustomSnackBar {
  constructor(private snackBarRef: MatSnackBarRef<CustomSnackBar>){ }

  onActionBtnClick() {
    this.snackBarRef.dismissWithAction();
  }
}
```

The code that opened the snackbar:

```ts
let snackBarRef = this.snackBar.openFromComponent(CustomSnackBar);
snackBarRef.onAction().subscribe(() => {
  console.log('Action button clicked!');
})
```

Comment: It shows dismissWithAction does not exists on the type MatSnackBarRef<CustomSnackBar>!!

Comment: @NishantVarshney Can you try `closeWithAction()`? What's your Angular Material version?